# Self adjustable CSS border width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div element as below for example:

```
<div style="height: 10%; width: 20%; border: 1px solid black">
     Div Content
</div>
```

Since the above div has height and width in %, I want the border width also to adjust when we resize the element. Looks like there is no way of denominating border width apart from pixel. So is there any idea on how to adjust the border width?

Comment: I would use media queries. Set diferent border width values to your containers dependin of width window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery. for example: `var x = $(".div-class").width() or .height` now you have div height or width in pixels. make some calculations to get border height. for exaple we need 10% of height. `var borderHeight = x *0.1;` now just give it for div `$("div-name").css("border-size",borderHeight + "px");`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with percentage padding and a wrapper with background color :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
         Div Content
     </div>
 </div> 

.wrapper {
    background: #000;
    padding: 1%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
}

.content {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rckbk9p6/